# how to write below xpath in java

Tags: selenium, webdriver

```
//div[@ng-if="subNav.state == 'active'"]
```

I tried like as below but getting **"InvalidSelectorException"**:

```
String active = "subNav.state == 'active'";
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@ng-if='"+active+"']"))
```

```html
<li class="active" on="subNav.state != '' && subNav.state != 'active'" ng-switch="" ng-repeat="subNav in navigation[activeNav].pages | filter:subNavFilter(navigation[activeNav].pages)">
 <div class="whereabouts ng-scope" ng-if="subNav.state == 'active'"></div>
 <span class="badge badge-active" aria-disabled="true" ng-if="subNav.state != 'complete'">6</span>
 <span class="ng-binding ng-scope" ng-switch-when="false">Loan</span>
</li>
```

Comment: Try to use  its parent tag element. Can you post your HTML code.?

Comment: @Saritha G.Thanks,.But here issue is in java we cannot user double 'double inverted comma(")' and while writing xpath we can not double  'single inverted comma(').I have work around to identify element by other means but i wanted to identify by above xpath.Aboveis the html structure of that section(2nd line i am trying to indentify):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there will be quotes used inside the value you should escape the quotes.And I would suggest go with double quotes to close all.
Here's the xpath

```
    String active = "subNav.state == 'active'";
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@ng-if=\"" + active + "\"]"));
```